# React app confusion setting state of nested child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm an embedded developer who is new to React and am struggling a bit with the behaviour of child components and nested child components.

I understand that for any component to be re-rendered, the state must change. I am using an example of a menu component that has an item component within.  When some global level event happens, I want to change the text displayed by the item components.

Here is a fiddle that shows some code that I would expect to work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-rain-8mfsp?file=/src/App.tsx

On clicking the div, the menu's setText function gets called, which calls into the item component, setting the state. This state is used in the render function of the item component, so I would expect both item and menu to be re-rendered.

Instead I get an error saying that I can't set the state of an object that hasn't yet been mounted.  I would have thought it had been mounted..

Perhaps the way I have linked the declared components with those in the render functions by calling this.componentname.render() is the issue - but how else could that be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey. You have too many concepts about React confused so answering your question/s will actually do you no good. It will be more beneficial to you to actually checkout the official documentation and go over the "fast-track" here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bird-qecj0?file=/src/App.tsx:0-899

I see that you are new to react. I would suggest you use hooks instead of class components.

Comment: Hi KnowYourElements, I really appreciate the working version, thanks.  It's interesting that while learning React it's been drilled into me that props are immutable and not to be used for content that will change, but you should use state instead for that.  Also, for my actual application, the item component will be fairly complex with several functions (It will actually be an array of checkboxes that changes dynamically and each checkbox has a different function), so I'm not sure I can avoid using a class component. Is it not possible the way that I attempted?

Comment: It is not possible to do the way you attempted. Simply, because that is not how React works. You can use class based or function based components. It doesn't really matter. But take note, function based components are newer relative to class based components.

I would recommend for you to read this simple guide. It uses class based components which may help you.
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#before-we-start-the-tutorial

Comment: Interesting, I thought I was starting to get React, but it obviously hasn't clicked with me yet. I will do that tutorial - cheers!